# How do i remove a "#" sign from a ms-access hyperlink field?

Tags: ms-access, sql-like, regexp-like

In a msaccess field you see an hyperlink f.e. https://stackoverflow.com when is open the field using F2 i see #https://stackoverflow.com#. How do i remove the # using an update query? Even selection query is hard

I tried the "Like" parameter but Like "#" dus not give any hits. I tried also ""#"" and "'#'" and ''#'' but no succes whatsoever.

no errors but also not the wanted result

Comment: If it is supposed to be a hyperlink field, you shouldn't remove the octothorpes.

Answer (score 1):

You can select records containing the hash/pound symbol (`#`) using the `like` pattern `*[#]*` e.g.:

```
select * from YourTable where YourTable.YourField like "*[#]*"
```

You can remove the hash/pound symbol (`#`) from the values held by such records using the [`replace`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/replace-function-6acf209b-01b7-4078-b4b8-e0a4ef67d181) function, e.g.:

```
update YourTable 
set YourTable.YourField = Replace(YourTable.YourField,"#","")
where YourTable.YourField like "*[#]*"
```

---

To remove the symbol from only the ends of the string, since URLs cannot contain spaces, you could use the following:

```
update YourTable
set YourTable.YourField = Trim(Replace(Replace(" " & YourTable.YourField & " "," #",""),"# ",""))
where YourTable.YourField like "[#]*" or YourTable.YourField like "*[#]"
```

Comment: This works fine. Using this solution i found that only the " #"  ad the start and te beginning of the string/link should be removed. How do i arrange that? A start of a solution is of course: Right([mytable].[myfield,1) Like "*[#]*" but how do i change the Replace code?

Answer (score 0):

A hash sign `#` in a text string in MS Access can be found in a search (and from there replaced) by wrapping it in square brackets, i.e. `[#]`